# Dart: multiple await for same future

Tags: dart, future, dart-async

I have recently seen some code example like below

```
Future<Null> ensureLogin() {...}

var login = ensureLogin();

Future functionA() async {
   await login;
   print("FunctionA finished");
}

Future functionB() async {
   await login;
   print("FunctionB finished");
}

void main() {
   functionA();
   functionB()
}
```

When the future completed, it prints out below:

```
FunctionA finished
FunctionB finished
```

Looks like we can have multiple await for the same future object? But how does this work under the hood? And what is it equivalent to Future? Maybe something like below?

```
login.then(functionA).then(fucntionB)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can register as many callbacks as you want with `then(...)` for a single `Future` instance.

Without `async`/`await` it would look like

```
Future functionA() async {
   login.then((r) {
     print("FunctionA finished");
   });
}

Future functionB() async {
   login.then((r) {
     print("FunctionB finished");
   });
}
```

When `login` completes, all registered callbacks will be called one after the other.

If `login` was already completed when `login.then((r) { ... })` is called, then the callback is called after the current sync code execution is completed.

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, even if it is orthogonal to the actual question, is that `var login = ensureLogin();` is a lazily initialized variable, so the value of `login` isn't computed until the first reference to the variable occurs (in `functionA`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use simply:

```dart
Future.wait(
  [
    method1(),
    method2(),
  ]
).then((){});
```